# Function that updates a useState hook when called in jsx it is causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that fetches data and updates a useState hook but when i call that function inside jsx it causes an infinite loop, I have tried to put a condition in jsx before i call the function to avoid infinite loop but then the function doesn't work properly. Below is my code

My Function

```
const fetchDataFnc = (booking) => {
  const fleetId = booking.booking_bids_fleet_id
  const bookingId = booking.booking_id
  console.log("fleetId" ,fleetId)
  if(booking.booking_bids_fleet_id){
    firebase.database().ref('fleets/' + 
      fleetId[0]).child("booking_bids").child(bookingId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      console.log("fleet snap",snapshot.val())
        setFirstPrice(snapshot.val().price[0])
        setAllPrices(snapshot.val().price)
        console.log("all the prices", snapshot.val().price)
        console.log("fleet collect", snapshot.val());
    });
  }
  if(booking.booking_bids_fleet_id){
    firebase.database().ref('booking/' + bookingId).child("booking_bids_prices").set({
      firstPrice
    });
  }
}
```

My Jsx

```
{selectedBooking.length > 0 ? selectedBooking.map((booking)=>{
                // showFirstPrice(booking)
                if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
                  fetchDataFnc(booking)
                }
                return( 
                  <>
                  {firstSel &&
                    <SelectedBooking
                      booking_ref={booking.booking_ref}
                      firstPrice={firstPrice}
                      booking={booking}
                      handleSettle={handleSettle}
                      setSettleAmount={setSettleAmount}
                      settleAmount={settleAmount}
                      allPrices={allPrices}
                      handleAccept={handleAccept}
                    />
                  } 
                  </>
                )
              }):
                <></> 
              }
```

Comment: can you complete your code, and add the useState declaration to provide clarity...

Comment: You should call your function outside the rendering phase. Try calling it inside a useEffect, example: as a side effect of selecting the booking if that makes sense :)

Here is the link of react docs

Answer (score 3):

Don't call a function which updates state *on every render*.  Updating state triggers a re-render, so the component will endlessly re-render and re-invoke the function.

You're *probably* looking for the `useEffect` hook.  For example, to call the function once when the component *first* loads and then not again afterward, pass an empty dependency array to the hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchDataFnc(booking);
}, []);
```

Though in this case `booking` is a dependency.  To re-invoke the function any time that dependency changes, add it to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchDataFnc(booking);
}, [booking]);
```

**Edit:** Linters may also require you to add the function itself to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchDataFnc(booking);
}, [booking, fetchDataFnc]);
```

This would lead to a probably next step of defining the function with the `useCallback` hook, so the function isn't re-created on every render but only when *its* dependencies change:

```
const fetchDataFnc = useCallback((booking) => {
  //...
}, [/* dependencies */]);
```

A linter can help you identify the dependencies to use there, but it's the same concept as with `useEffect` really.  Anything that could change and, when it does, should update the function to use its new value would be in the dependency array.

(This practice sometimes requires re-thinking how we structure functions, leading to more pro-actively thinking about dependencies and closures and all around cleaner and more stable JavaScript code.)

---

As an aside, you also probably don't want to do all this *inside the JSX*.  The logic of the component, such as state and effects and helper functions, all happens before the JSX.  The JSX is the result returned by the component, which itself is a function like any other.

Comment: by the lint rule AFAIK he will need to add `fetchDataFnc` as dependency too, which might need a `useCallback`

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: *If* it gets defined with `useCallback` then yes.  Otherwise, if it's defined on every render as-is then they wouldn't want to add it as a dependency because it would be "different" on every render.  But yes, making use of `useCallback` would certainly be a good next step.

Comment: Yeah I meant the linter will anyway complain about `fetchDataFnc`. And directly putting it as dependency is usually not a way out, as it gets recreated, and may fire each time.

Comment: I am unable to call the function on the useEffect simply because it says the dependency is not defined does the hook go into the function?, do i need to turn the whole function to a custom hook?

Comment: @vnashthebioprophet: Is it telling you that fetchDataFnc itself needs to be added to the dependency array?  If so, add it.  You might also take the next step and use the useCallback hook to define fetchDataFnc with its own dependency array, so it’s not re-defined on every render.